# Get collection by user id in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

The biggest problem is I'm totally new to `MongoDB`. I know how to do it in `SQL` but am unable to shift my thinking into `NoSQL`. I have this model:

```
var accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  isPremium: Boolean,
  website: []
});
```

I'm using mongoose so it creates Id, username, and password automatically. My registered user looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('5a79c89b59b6042a5d89584b'),
  websites: ['a.com', 'b.com', 'c.com'],
  username: 'a@a.a',
  isPremium: false,
  hash:
    'a long hash',
  salt: 'a long salt',
  __v: 0,
};
```

I want want to write out the `websites` array. I want to grab only the websites under a certain user. (Don't want others to just see all websites).

How would I do it? Would I pass the userId after a click or make it in a session? And would the 'query' look like?

Comment: you need a mongoose model something like var account = mongoose.model('Acount', accountSchema ); then do something like account.findById( id of target account ).websites

Comment: So I need to create a new module? Also how would I get the id? Should I make it a session variable? If something like this exists in Node

Comment: yeah create a module that exports your model so that you can import it and use it elsewhere. No dont put that in a session variable. You question lead with having the user id I am assuming that the account id. You dont need to use the id you could use any piece of information you have account that account by using just .find() look up mongoose queries to get a better idea.

Comment: So what's wrong with the model I posted above?

Comment: what you have posted is the schema and an example object. refer back to my comment. You should really go read the documentation. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

First define your model as a separate module

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const accountSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
  isPremium: Boolean,
  website: []
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('account',accountSchema);
```

Then you can use this model everywhere in your code

```
const account = require('yourModulePath');

account.findOne({YouSearchParameters}).
then((account) => {

  // let websites = account.website
  // Do you logic

})
```

You also can filter result with .select

```
account.findOne({YouSearchParameters}).select({ "website": 1, "_id": 0}).then((account)
```

So you will just get your array of websites

Comment: That's great! Thanks! Sorry for the late response. Had a lot on my head